# QLineEdit and custom function incompatibility

Tags: python, string, pyqt4

I'm trying to finish my project with Python and PyQt4 and I'm having an issue passing a QLineEdit variable through a function I made. The string should work as an url and when I pass it through my first argument, which tries to read the url and get its content, it throws me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "programa2.py", line 158, in on_link_clicked
    download_mango(self.a, self.path2)

  File "c:\Users\Poblet\ManGet\mango.py", line 19, in download_mango
    urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(url).read() # We read the URL

  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 386, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()

AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'get_type'
```

Which is triggered by the following action:

```
def on_link_clicked(self):
    self.a = self.linkEdit.displayText()
    download_mango(self.a, self.path2)
```

And I'm completely lost. Could it be a PyQt4 issue or something wrong with my function?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please paste your code. what's download_mango ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post enough code to justify your statement that

> The string should work as an url and when I pass it through my first argument

Looks like you are passing a QString into urlopen.  Just wrap it in `str()` and you should be OK.

```
>>> url = QString('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121475')
>>> urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
### this generates your error ending with
AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'get_type'

>>> urllib2.urlopen(str(url)).read()
### works
```

Comment: Thanks! I always thought QLineEdit passed things like a string already. Now I won't be repeating the same mistake twice.

Comment: I've started using PySide because it  removes  "QString and other useless Qt stuff for python developers, like QVariant".  Like the license better too.

Answer (score 0):

self.a is missing

> "**http://**"or "**https://**"

try

```
download_mango("http://"+self.a,self.path2)
```

see http://www.nullege.com/codes/search/urllib2.Request.get_type